# Creating comments in post are not being save in the actual post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my code i created a Post and in the post are comments, i created the associations with has_many and belongs to but i can only connect the creating of a comment in a post via rails consolo and if i try to create a new commment in my post the comment doesnt get saved in the post but i can see the created comment in my comments/index

i tried filling my create method in post with the association but i couldnt make it work

this is my comment controller:

```
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /comments
  # GET /comments.json
  def index
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  # GET /comments/1
  # GET /comments/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /comments/new
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  # GET /comments/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /comments
  # POST /comments.json
  def create
    #@Course.comment = Course.find(params[:post_id]) <--what are tryed
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1
  # PATCH/PUT /comments/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update(comment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /comments/1
  # DELETE /comments/1.json
  def destroy
    @comment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to comments_url, notice: 'Comment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

and this are my associations

Post:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
    validates :user_courses, presence: true
    has_many :student_courses
    has_many :students, through: :student_courses

    has_many :course_comments
    has_many :comments, through: :course_comments

    has_many :teacher_courses
    has_many :teacher, through: :teacher_courses
end
```

Comment:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :course_comments
    has_many :courses, through: :course_comments
end
```

CourseComment:

```
class CourseComment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :comment
end
```

what is supposed to happend is, i enter to Course(post) and the i click in new comment the loads the form_for and i create the post and get redirect to the actual post no to the comments/index so pls i need some advice for what can i do or if im missing something

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with your data model. You setup a `many-to-many` relationship between `Course` and `Comment`...but, logically, it should be a `one-to-many` relationship. A comment can only belong to one course (I'm assuming?), so I don't see a purpose for your `CourseComment` model.

The reason you can associate a comment with a post in your console is because you are doing it explicitly. You need to do the same thing in your controller.

The way you do this will depend on how your routes are setup. If you have comments nested under posts in your routes file and are passing in the post, then you can grab the post and create the association with something like this...

```
@comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
@comment.post = Post.find(params[:post_id]
```

If your routes are not nested then you will need to manually pass the `post_id` in as a param.

Comment: i have to define ```post_id``` in the post table or rails take the one created by default?

Comment: I was also reading yesterday and yes, I realize that my relationships between comments and posts are poorly established, so it is supposed to be one_to_many instead of has_many

Answer (score -1):

If you want to associate it with a `Post` when you hit `POST /comments`, then you need to whitelist `post_id` in the `comment_params` method. Otherwise, it will be stripped out of your request.